# Flutter build Undefined Symbol Error message

Tags: flutter, xcode

[image]
This is my error message

[image]
this is my pubspec.yaml

pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.7.0'

I use this line in my pod file.

I am running the Mac Air m1, with MacOs 13.3, Xcode 14.3, and Flutter 3.7.9, I updated everything today, now I am getting this error. I already made pod install and so on